# How to know when scroller of the div reaches the bottom - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

How can I fire another event whenever the scroll of a div reaches its bottom. 
I do not want to use jscroll.com or infinite-scroll.
Using `$(window).bind("scroll", function (){}` is not working for me.
Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#div').bind('scroll', function() {
     if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
     {
         alert('bottom');
     }
});
```

Comment: This works like a charm, but I am still getting an issue with it. Lets take an ex of facebook, & I have hundred post to show, loading in the stack of 20. Whenever scroll reaches the bottom next 20 shows up. So, this works for the first time I scroll down, but when I scroll down next time, this alert - alert('bottom') is popping twice. Is there any reason like scrolls touches the bottom twice or anything. Any hint??

Comment: third batch will probably fire 3 times alert('bottom')... use unique identifiers for event divs... and your last loaded should be stored in a var and then rebind the scroll event so only the bottom-most div will fire the event or use a dedicated div for event fireing and load the batches right before it so it will be pushed down again.

Comment: I am using its class name as identifier which is unique for this div, & actually it is an un-ordered list which has a no of li. & scroll event is firing when ul reaches its bottom. & How to capture that the scroll event for last li is getting fired?

Comment: try this way: <ul>...</ul><div id="sensor"></div> and the js $('#sensor').bind(....)

Comment: No, it isn't helping. Still getting triggered twice.

Comment: Hi, I implemented the workaround as to check for unique element for it. Can you help me with one more thing, What if I need to check for the scroll, when it reaches the top. How to edit $(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight this for top?? I tried a few things but not working.

Comment: Sorry to ask such a dumb question, it will be scrollTop() == 0. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this....

```
$("#mydiv").scroll( function() {
if($(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() == $(this).outerHeight()) {
// what you want to do ...
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

somthing like this

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var window_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var document_height = $(document).height();

    if (window_height + window_scroll == document_height) {
       alert("bottom");
    } 
});
```

example:

[demo](http://arammkrtchyan.info/example)

Comment: This works like a charm, but I am still getting an issue with it. Lets take an ex of facebook, & I have hundred post to show, loading in the stack of 20. Whenever scroll reaches the bottom next 20 shows up. So, this works for the first time I scroll down, but when I scroll down next time, this alert - alert('bottom') is popping twice. Is there any reason like scrolls touches the bottom twice or anything. Any hint??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:100px; height:10000px;background-color:red;"></div>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function() {
            $(window).bind("scroll", function (){ 
                console.log("SCROLL : " + $(window).scrollTop() 
                    + " - " + $(window).innerHeight() 
                    + " - " + document.body.clientHeight);
                if ($(window).scrollTop() + document.body.clientHeight >= $(window).innerHeight()) {
                            alert('Bottom!');
                }
            });
        });
</script>
</html>
```

This will work for chrome, you may need to use other commands for other browsers.